# dragging on one TextView drags entire collection in SwiftUI with onDrag modifier

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to work through the EmojiArt app on Stanford 193p 2021, if that reference helps. Otherwise, as the title says, I'm trying to add an onDrag modifier on each of the emoji chars, but it appears as if when I drag on one, the entire string of emoji chars gets dragged. how to fix this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct EmojiArtDocumentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var document: EmojiArtDocument
    let defaultmojiFontSize: CGFloat = 40
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            documentBody
            palette
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    var documentBody: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow
                ForEach(document.emojis) { emoji in
                    Text(emoji.text)
                        .font(.system(size: fontSize(for: emoji)))
                        .position(position(for: emoji, in: geometry))
                }
            }
        }
//        .onDrop(of: [.plainText], isTargeted: nil) {
//            providers, location in
//            return false
//        }
    }
    
    private func drop(providers: [NSItemProvider], at location: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        false
    }
    
    private func fontSize(for emoji: EmojiArt.Emoji) -> CGFloat {
        CGFloat(emoji.size)
    }
    
    private func position(for emoji: EmojiArt.Emoji, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGPoint {
        convertFromEmojiCoordinates((emoji.x, emoji.y), in: geometry)
    }
    
    private func convertFromEmojiCoordinates(_ location: (x: Int, y: Int), in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGPoint {
        let center = geometry.frame(in: .local).center
        return CGPoint(
            x: center.x + CGFloat(location.x),
            y: center.y + CGFloat(location.y)
        )
    }
    
    var palette: some View {
        ScrollingEmojisView(emojis: testemojis)
            .font(.system(size: defaultmojiFontSize))
    }
    
    let testemojis = ""
}

struct ScrollingEmojisView: View {
    let emojis: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(emojis.map {String($0) }, id: \.self) { emoji in
                    Text(emoji)
                        .onDrag {
                            NSItemProvider(object: emoji as NSString)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EmojiArtDocumentView(document: EmojiArtDocument())
    }
}

extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to insert ZStack and modify ForEach of the documentBody property as below:

```
ForEach(document.emojis) { emoji in
    ZStack {
        Text(emoji.text)
            .font(.system(size: fontSize(for: emoji)))
    }
    .position(position(for: emoji, in: geometry))
    .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { dragValue in
                document.moveEmoji(emoji, by: dragValue.translation, in: geometry)
            }
    )
}
```

This way, each ZStack will be recognized as a separate draggable view, and you will be able to drag individual emoji characters.

Comment: it turns out the code was working just fine. it was my clicking on the emoji that was wrong. I would start dragging before I got the weird scaling indicator showing that the emoji is ready to drag. an unfortunate side effect of working with emulators rather than the device